# Having problem with SyntaxError on elif statement/condition

Tags: python, debugging

I am attempting to debug the section of code shown below. I am part of a beginner coding program where I am  attempting to learn Python, and I am trying to debug a section of code involving tax brackets. I contacted one of the support staff and she states that my code looks fine, but I still get a SyntaxError reading from line 19 that states that "elif" is the root of the problem.

```
def income_tax_single(income, round_income):
    
    if round_income:
        income = round(income) # round to nearest integer
    else:
        income = income # do not round it
    if (income <= 9875):
        tax_bracket = 0.1
        income_tax = (0.1 * income)
    elif (income >= 9876) and (income <= 40125):
        tax_bracket = 0.12
        income_tax = 987.50 + (0.12 * (income - 9875))
    elif (income >= 40126) and (income <= 85525):
        tax_bracket = 0.22
        income_tax = 4617.50 + (0.22 * (income - 40125))
    elif (income >= 85526) and (income <= 163300):
        tax_bracket = 0.24
        income_tax = 14605.50 + (0.24 * (income - 85525)
    elif (income >= 163301) and (income <= 207350):
        tax_bracket = 0.32
        income_tax = 33271.50 + (0.32 * (income - 163300))
    elif (income >= 207351) and (income <= 518400):
        tax_bracket = 0.35
        income_tax = 47367.50 + (0.35 * (income - 207350))
    elif (income >= 518401):
        tax_bracket = 0.37
        income_tax = 156235 + (0.37 * (income - 518400))                             
                                 
        return tax_bracket, return income_tax
```

I reverted the code and did the whole thing again, only to receive similar results. I contacted a member of the support staff and said that while the code looks good, she is not experienced enough to handle my problem. As of the typing of this post, ChatGPT cannot be accessed on my computer due to connection issues. I was expecting the entire code to be corrected and for it to be correct, but it instead gives me a syntax error.

Comment: you are missing a closing parethesis

Comment: More specifically, on line 18.

Comment: And `return tax_bracket, return income_tax` won't work as well. Did you mean `return tax_bracket, income_tax`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Moreover, the statement is indented too deeply.

Comment: Also, please always include the complete, exact error message, not some vague description of it. And don't use ChatGPT to generate code. It's just plain crap for that.